# c# - WPF opening file externally not terminating process when closed and not parsing data

Tags: c#, wpf, command-line-arguments, vcf-vcard

I've recently been working on a vCard parser that opens a vCard file and populates a series of textboxes with data from the files. When my application is associated with a vCard, the vCard opens the program and the filename is passed via a statup function to a function called readVcard. This is then split by each BEGIN:VCARD statement into an array called string. If the length is greater than 1, the Window shows a dialog with the data from the index in an array and when that dialog is closed a new one opens until the contents have been read. When the last Window is closed, the program doesn't terminate if the file is opened externally but if it opens internally it works fine!

I also have an issue with it parsing the data from readVcard. I have tested it and the data is used in the readVcard function, but not passed on to the parser function, where it actually parses it. Again this works fine when the file is opened internally, but not externally.

This my startup event:

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Args != null && e.Args.Count() > 0)
        {
            this.Properties["ArbitraryArgName"] = e.Args[0];
        }
        base.OnStartup(e);

        if (Application.Current.Properties["ArbitraryArgName"] != null)
        {
            string fname = Application.Current.Properties["ArbitraryArgName"].ToString();
            MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            mw.readVcard(fname);
            //Application curApp = Application.Current;
            //curApp.Shutdown();
        }

    }
```

The read vCard function is below:

```
                    string input = File.ReadAllText(fname);//read through file

                progressBar1.Value = 10;

                input = input ?? "---This file did not contain any text---jlb95";

                if (input != "---This file did not contain any text---jlb95" || input != "")
                {

                    if (!input.Contains("BEGIN:VCARD") || !input.Contains("END:VCARD"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This file: " + fname + " is not formatted correctly." + "\r\n Error: 001", "File not formatted correctly", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                        progressBar1.Value = 0;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        String[] vArray = input.Split(new string[] { "BEGIN:VCARD" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        if (vArray.Length > 1)
                        {
                            MessageBoxResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("This vCard File contains multiple contacts. The program can loop through them and will open a new Window for each one" +
                                " when the current window is closed or it can open the first contact. Do you want to open all the contacts?", "File contains multiple contacts", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question
                                , MessageBoxResult.Yes);

                            if (dialog == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                            {
                                progressBar1.Value = 20;

                                foreach (var v in vArray)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show(v);
                                    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                                    mainWindow.parser(v, fname);
                                    mainWindow.ShowDialog();

                                }

                                progressBar1.Value = 0;

                                return;
                            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry: fixed it. The method didn't actually call mw to show, so the data wasn't being processed and it was left hanging when the current window was closed.

```
        if (Application.Current.Properties["ArbitraryArgName"] != null)
        {
            string fname = Application.Current.Properties["ArbitraryArgName"].ToString();
            MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            mw.Show();
            mw.readVcard(fname);
        }
```